# I want to fetch output values from database against my input values PostgresSQL

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql

I have setup a table in my database in which output value is set against its input and value tuple, and .for example my input is scoring with string "Calculation_score", and in database , there is value set against to this string which is "10".

```
**Table :**

**input**            **value**            **output value**

scoring                 Calculation_score         10
scoring                 Credit_score              20
scoring                 Monthly_score             30
scoring                 weekly_score              5
```

My code:

```
import psycopg2

value = "Calculation_score"
input = "scoring"
con = psycopg2.connect(database="myDB", user="postgres", password="admin", host="localhost", port="5432")
cur = con.cursor()


result = cur.execute("""SELECT input, input_type, value, output FROM value_rules WHERE input = :input
AND value = :value""", {"input": input, "value": value}).fetchone()

print(result)
return result['output']
```

I am querying database from python to get my output value, i dont understand whats wrong with this query, it gives me error( which is below ) ,even when i use "==" in place of ":" .

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    """, {"input": input, "value": value}).fetchone()
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 4: WHERE input = :input
                      ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be more specific on the setting the query statement and add the expected format character `s` using parameterized query as follows

```
>>> # example
>>> q = 'SELECT id, name FROM customer WHERE id = %(cid)s;'
>>> cursor.execute(q, {'cid': 1})
>>> cursor.query
    b'SELECT id, name FROM customer WHERE id = 1;'

>>> # so in your case you can do 
>>> q = 'SELECT input, input_type, value, output FROM value_rules WHERE input = %(input)s AND value = %(value)s' 
>>> cursor.execute(q, {'input': 'Calculation_score', 'value': 'scoring' })
```

Check more on the [docs here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters)

Comment: ```
rows = cur.fetchone()
print(rows)
``` 
i tried your snippet, but in output it only returns None

Comment: does the `cursor.query` return the SQL statement you expect? Post a sample `print(cursor.query)`

Comment: @xpertdev I have edited to put your expected values for the params.

Comment: i tried your snippet. ```cur.execute(q, {'input': input, 'value': value })
rows = cur.fetchone()
print(rows)``  its output is none .

Comment: Checkign hold on

Comment: return float(row['output']) i am returning output from that result but it says "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203394/discussion-between-gideon-maina-and-xpertdev).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import psycopg2

value = "Calculation_score"
input = "monthly_inquiries"
con = psycopg2.connect(database="myDB", user="postgres", password="admin", host="localhost", port="5432")
cur = con.cursor()

 cur.execute("SELECT input, input_type, value, output FROM value_rules WHERE input = %s
AND value = %s;", (input, value)) 

result = cur.fetchone()

    print(result)
```

Indeed, execute doesnt fetch the rows, We have to do the fetch with the cursor (cur)

Comment: thankyou for your response, it throws AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchone' error